# What's the different between these properties?

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a class `RootView` with two properties, declared in different ways. Now I want to know what the difference between those two declarations is?

```
class RootView: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Variables
    var rightMenu: RightMenu = RightMenu()
    let right = RightMenu()

}
```

Please guide me about difference between `right` and `rightMenu`?

Answer (score 1):

Both are of same type, but here below are few points that will tell when you need `Type Annotation` and when not.

Here are few concepts.

1. Your `rightMenu` is a variable, you reassign a value of same type at alter point, where as `right` is a constant, you can not reassign a new value.
2. Swift introduced type inference concept, where if you assign a value(literals) with out providing type, it will directly determine the the type for you. So need to provide explicitly type for it. Here your both `rightMenu` and `right` are of same type.

Ideally no need to provide explicitly type if you are assigning initial value to a variable at the time of declaration.

```
a) var myClass: MyClass!
```

Here you need to provide type, because no intial value is provided and you want to assign value to it at later point.

```
b) var myClass = MyClass()
```

Here no need, because you provided a initial value and Swift compiler will automatically determine the type for it.

In Swift providing/declaring type for a variable or constant after `:` symbol is called `Type Annotation`. For more details, see [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)

Comment: my friend you tell me rightMenu:RightMenu = RightMenu() and right = RightMenu() are of same type ????

Comment: @MKFB, Both are of same type, but one is constant and one is variable as per your code.

Comment: @MKFB, rightMenu:RightMenu() better as per standard.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is the mutability of those two variables. You can change `rightMenu` because it's mutable. However, `right` is not mutable. It means that `right` is a constant.

From the syntax prospectives, you don't necessarily to add `:RightMenu` when you declare `rightMenu`. Like you declare `right`, compiler will infer the object as type of `RightMenu`. But, when you want only to declare something without initializing it. You probably need to use `:<type>?` to tell the compiler that the type of this `ivar` and the value might be missing.